# Установка и настройка apache

Tags: apache

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему не загружается apache. Выполняю все по инструкции в книге Н.Прохоренок "Джентельментский набор веб-мастера", указываю localhost, загрузка идет до конца. Но потом оказывается, что ничего не загрузилось и в файле ошибок запись: укажите настоящее имя сервера, а не 127.0.0.1. Что надо делать? Указывать при загрузке вместо localhost свой IP?

Comment: А на конфигурацию взглянуть можно?

Answer (score 1):

Немного поправлю.

В файле `%systemroot%/system32/etc/hosts` дожна ещё обязательно быть строка

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
```

т.е. полный текст файла будет тогда

```
127.0.0.1 localhost127.0.0.1 you_test_site_name
```

ещё бы неплохо знать какая операционная система стоит на компе, где вы запускаете dnwr (как понимаю, речь идёт именно о нём). Дело в том, что при запуске, он автоматически изменяет hosts-файл как того требует его конфигурация и естественно, что разрешения на изменения файла должны быть. В Windows 7 по умолчанию этих прав нет.

Answer (score 0):

Не видя конфигурации, трудно ответить. Посмотрите, есть ли в виртуальных хостах (httpd.conf) имя сервера:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>    ServerName x    DocumentRoot /var/www/x/</VirtualHost>
```

x - это имя вашего сервера. Ну и в /etc/hosts должно быть такое

```
127.0.0.1 x
```